# Setting arbitrary nodes positions in a Graphviz state machine diagram

Tags: graphviz, dot

Grapviz normally formats diagrams according to fixed styles.

I would like to set nodes positions of this graph:

[image: standard Graphviz output]

generated with this code:

```
digraph finite_state_machine {
    # rankdir=LR;
    size="8,5"
    node [shape = doublecircle]; S E;
    node [shape = circle];
    S  -> S0   [ label = "0/-" ];
    S  -> S1   [ label = "1/-" ];

    S0 -> S1   [ label = "1/-" ];
    S1 -> S0   [ label = "0/-" ];

    S0 -> S00  [ label = "0/0" ];
    S1 -> S11  [ label = "1/1" ];

    S0 -> E  [ label = "$/-" ];
    S1 -> E  [ label = "$/-" ];

    S00 -> S00 [ label = "0/0" ];
    S11 -> S11 [ label = "1/1" ];

    S00 -> S1  [ label = "1/0" ];
    S11 -> S0  [ label = "0/1" ];

    S00 -> E [ label = "$/0" ];
    S11 -> E [ label = "$/1" ];


}

// http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/directed/fsm.html
// dot -Tpng example_fsm.dot > example_fsm.png
```

to look like this one:
[image: desired diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rank = same` is your friend. I also have added some weight for greater symmetry.

```
digraph finite_state_machine 
{
    size="8,5"
    { rank = same; S0  S1  }
    { rank = same; S00 S11 }

    node [shape = doublecircle]; 
    S; E;
    node [shape = circle];
    S0; S1; S00; S11;

    S  -> S0   [ label = "0/-" ];
    S  -> S1   [ label = "1/-" ];

    S0 -> S1   [ label = "1/-" ];
    S1 -> S0   [ label = "0/-" ];

    S0 -> S00  [ label = "0/0", weight = 8 ];
    S1 -> S11  [ label = "1/1", weight = 8 ];

    S0 -> E  [ label = "$/-" ];
    S1 -> E  [ label = "$/-" ];

    S00 -> S00 [ label = "0/0" ];
    S11 -> S11 [ label = "1/1" ];

    S00 -> S1  [ label = "1/0" ];
    S11 -> S0  [ label = "0/1" ];

    S00 -> E [ label = "$/0" ];
    S11 -> E [ label = "$/1" ];
}
```

yields

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution, this one is using the `constraint` and `dir` attributes instead of `weight`:

```
digraph finite_state_machine {
    size="8,5"
    node [shape = doublecircle]; S E;
    node [shape = circle];
    S  -> S0   [ label = "0/-" ];
    S  -> S1   [ label = "1/-" ];

    S0 -> S00  [ label = "0/0" ];
    S1 -> S11  [ label = "1/1" ];

    S00 -> E [ label = "$/0" ];
    S11 -> E [ label = "$/1" ];

    S0 -> E  [ label = "$/-" ];
    S1 -> E  [ label = "$/-" ];

    S1 -> S00  [ label = "1/0", dir=back ];
    S0 -> S11  [ label = "0/1", dir=back ];

    edge[constraint=false];
    S0 -> S1   [ label = "1/-" ];
    S1 -> S0   [ label = "0/-" ];

    S00 -> S00 [ label = "0/0" ];
    S11 -> S11 [ label = "1/1" ];
}
```

[Result as visualized with GraphvizFiddle](http://stamm-wilbrandt.de/GraphvizFiddle/?1448954161173#digraph%20finite_state_machine%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20size%3D%228%2C5%22%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bshape%20%3D%20doublecircle%5D%3B%20S%20E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bshape%20%3D%20circle%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20S%20%20-%3E%20S0%20%20%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%220%2F-%22%20%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20S%20%20-%3E%20S1%20%20%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%221%2F-%22%20%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20S0%20-%3E%20S00%20%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%220%2F0%22%20%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20S1%20-%3E%20S11%20%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%221%2F1%22%20%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20S00%20-%3E%20E%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%22%24%2F0%22%20%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20S11%20-%3E%20E%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%22%24%2F1%22%20%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20S0%20-%3E%20E%20%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%22%24%2F-%22%20%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20S1%20-%3E%20E%20%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%22%24%2F-%22%20%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20S1%20-%3E%20S00%20%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%221%2F0%22%2C%20dir%3Dback%20%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20S0%20-%3E%20S11%20%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%220%2F1%22%2C%20dir%3Dback%20%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20edge%5Bconstraint%3Dfalse%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20S0%20-%3E%20S1%20%20%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%221%2F-%22%20%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20S1%20-%3E%20S0%20%20%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%220%2F-%22%20%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20S00%20-%3E%20S00%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%220%2F0%22%20%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20S11%20-%3E%20S11%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%221%2F1%22%20%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A)

Comment: Thank you very much. Would be also possible to adjust particular node in x,y direction?